# Removing Nan from a list of dataframe in R

Tags: r, list, nan

I am trying to convert `NaN` into zeroes. And, the code I am using is as follows

```
myfiles6 <- lapply(myfiles6, function(x) {x[is.nan(x)] <- 0; x})
```

but it gives an error as

> `Error in is.nan(x) : default method not implemented for type 'list'`

What could be the solution?

Comment: as the error says, you `is.nan` works for vectors, May be you need `lapply(myfiles6, function(dat) {dat[] <- lapply(dat, function(x) replace(x, is.nan(x), 0)); dat})`

Comment: this works but I would be too happy if it can be simplified, I guess it is a nested function.

Comment: Perhaps you can use `map(myfiles6, ~ .x %>% mutate_all(~ replace(., is.nan(.), 0)))` from `tidyverse`

Comment: thanks this looks familiar.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following code:

```
is.nan.data.frame <- function(x)
  do.call(cbind, lapply(x, is.nan))

myfile6[is.nan(myfile6)] <- 0
```

Comment: same `list` error produced.